# Replace values between parentheses using Javascript and Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace the text between two parentheses using Regex in Javascript. For example:

> var x = "I need to go (now)";

I need to replace 'now' with 'tomorrow'. I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
x.replace(/\(now)\b/g, 'tomorrow');
```

Comment: Use `x = x.replace('(now)', '(tomorrow)');`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please search for your question first. Also read the [help]

Comment: You don't need Regex for such trivial problem. Use String's methods, as @anubhava suggested

Comment: @hindmost You do not actually know how complex the search is. Perhaps it is a generic "replace something in brackets with something else" more than once in a sentence

Comment: @anubhava does that replace all occurrences? I think it replaces only one

Comment: That is correct. Only one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"I need to know (now)".replace(/\(now\)/g, 'tomorrow');
```

You don't need the `\b` and you need to escape the second `)`.

Comment: Does that replace all occurrences?

Comment: The code in my post will replace all occurrences because of the `g` flag at the end of the regex.  Remove it to only replace the first occurrence.